# How to get data like Auth::user()->email; for custom auth table

Tags: laravel, authentication, backend, laravel-8

So i have changed the default Auth table form user to Accounts like this in config\auth.php :

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'accounts',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'accounts',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'accounts',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'accounts' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Akun::class,
    ],
],

'passwords' => [
    'accounts' => [
        'provider' => 'accounts',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
```

Of course on Akun model I have changed the model Configuration like this

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Akun extends Authenticatable
{
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'accounts';

protected $fillable = [
    'nip',
    'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];
}
```

I  tried to log in with my login system and it can redirect correctly, this is my checklogin function

```
 function checklogin(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'nip'   => 'required',
        'password'  => 'required'
    ]);
    $akun_data = array(
        'nip' =>  $request->get('nip'),
        'password'  =>  $request->get('password')
    );
    if(Auth::attempt($akun_data)){
        return redirect('login/successlogin');
    }else{
        return back()->with('pesan','NIP atau Password salah');
    }
}
```

**But how can I get 'nip' data like Auth::user()->name; or something like that** . I'm new on laravel , I know it can be very easy if I'm using user table . But i have to use this Accounts table as default Auth.

Comment: You shouldn't really need to do anything else. You've already modified the default provider model to `Akun`

Comment: run php artisan config:clear

Comment: so how can i get 'nip' data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question.
Yes you can get your data with Auth::user() , even you changed the default table user.
But make sure in your default table user , there is a column called id and primary.
and in your Migration add this code:

```
$table->id();
```

You can get your data with just type

```
Auth::user()->column_name;
```

And make sure you have added

```
use Auth;
```

on the top of Controller class

Answer (score 0):

as you don't have `email` field so you should use manually login via `auth()->login()` function so your code will be like this

```php
function checklogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nip'   => 'required',
        'password'  => 'required'
    ]);

    $akun = Akun::where('nip', $request->get('nip'))->first();
    if (!$akun) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'User not found.');
    }

    if (\Hash::check($request->get('password'), $akun->password)) {
        auth()->login($akun);
        return redirect('login/successlogin');
    } else {
        return back()->with('pesan', 'NIP atau Password salah');
    }
}
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: if i changed 'nip' with 'email' . It would give Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'. Because yeah I've set it to Akun::class and there is no email column in there. when I tried to use dd(Auth::user()) after the login system. It showed 'null', is that should be like that?

Comment: do you mean if(!akun) ? because it'll always return back 'User not found' if i didn't change it .when i changed it with if(!akun),  it worked well too as login system. But when i try to dd(Auth::user()) it will always return null and if i go to Routes that i protect with middleware('auth') it will always bring back to the login page.

Comment: `auth()->login($akun);` if it works then `auth()->user()` it should work and yes it is `!$akun`

Comment: i tried auth()->user(), it returns null too haha, is there any step that I missed or forgot to change default auth table from user to account ?

Comment: I Want to get 'nip' data and use it.to get more data from database. I don't know how to get it.